# Display Park Name and Time outside Loop

Tags: java, arrays

How do I display the `parkName` and `time` outside the for loop?

```java
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    System.out.print("\n\nEnter park name: ");
    String parkName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter run time: ");
    String runTime = input.nextLine();

    //convert to double the user input which was a string
    //create new variable for time as double

    Double time = Double.parseDouble(runTime);
    parkRunner.recordNewRuns(parkName, time);
}
```

Comment: You just declare the variable outside the loop, and probably store it in an array. But I think that is done in `parkRunner.recordNewRuns`. Can you post the full context of the required code here?

Comment: @BlackPearl i have tried this but it keeps saying "illegal start of expression"                 public void PrintRuns(){
      for(int i=0; i<this.numberOfRuns; i++ )

     {


      System.out.println( "\nPark Name: " + this.parkName.get(i));
      System.out.println( "Run Time: " + this.time.get(i));

     }

   }

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is store the records in a `Map` inside your `recordNewRuns` method and print the map at the end.

```
public class ParkRunner {

    static Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap();

    public static void recordNewRuns(String parkName, double time) {
        map.put(parkName, time);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            System.out.print("\n\nEnter park name: ");
            String parkName = input.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter run time: ");
            String runTime = input.nextLine();

            // convert to double the user input which was a string
            // create new variable for time as double

            Double time = Double.parseDouble(runTime);

            ParkRunner.recordNewRuns(parkName, time);
        }

        System.out.println(map);

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make ParkRunner Object Arraylist outside of the the loop and inside the loop save your inputs in that array list and after getting inputs, Print them using a another for loop.

```
ArrayList<ParkRunner> parkRunnerList = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    System.out.print("\n\nEnter park name: ");
    String parkName = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter run time: ");
    String runTime = input.nextLine();

    //convert to double the user input which was a string
    //create new variable for time as double

    Double time = Double.parseDouble(runTime);
    ParkRunner temp = new ParkRunner(parkName, runTime);
    parkRunnerList.add(temp);
}

for(int j=1; j<=5; j++) {
    System.out.println("id:- "+ (j));
    System.out.println("name:- "+ parkRunnerList.get(j).getName());
    System.out.println("time:- "+ parkRunnerList.get(j).getRunTime());
}
```

It is the simplest way of doing it.